# iPhone 4 can't upgrade to iOS 8 to play newer games

Tags: ios

I am using an iPhone 4 with iOS 7 and trying to download games that require iOS 8.0 or higher, however I can't upgrade the iOS. Why can't I upgrade to iOS 8?

Comment: The duplicate should be the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

You can't update to iOS 8 with iPhone 4. You need at least an iPhone 4S to install iOS 8 to play the games.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 4 can only go up to iOS 7.1.2, where iPhone 4S can go the latest (currently 9.3.2).

Sources: [iPhone 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_4) | [iPhone 4S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_4S)