# How do I upgrade an iPhone 4 from iOS 7.1.2 to iOS 8 or 9

Tags: ios, upgrade, iphone

I have an iPhone 4 and I need to upgrade from 7.1.2 to iOS 8 or 9. I would like to ask how I can get iOS 8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone 4 can't upgrade to iOS 8 to play newer games](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/246093/iphone-4-cant-upgrade-to-ios-8-to-play-newer-games)

Comment: George, I think this question has a better answer than the duplicate, in fact I proposed a that as duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 3):

You can't upgrade an iPhone 4 to a newer version than 7.1.2. iOS 8 only supports iPhone 4S to iPhone 6 Plus. iOS 9 supports iPhone 4S to iPhone 6S Plus/iPhone SE.

An iOS support matrix is available here: [iOS Support Matrix](http://iossupportmatrix.com/) (additionally: [pdf download](http://iossupportmatrix.com/s/MatrixV4b6.pdf))